# JavaFX Selecting a TREE ITEM behaves does not work in the first walk behaves correctly after that

Tags: treeview, javafx-8

I have a tree of family members. I am attempting to provide a SEARCH facility which will allow me to select all the tree items where person name contains the SEARCH name. See this screen shot, though the first item matches RAJA it is not selected.

[image]

Now when I click on the LOCATE button again, the selections are correct as you can see.

[image]

This is the code for LOCATE BUTTON CLICKED.

```
    @FXML
void onLocateClicked(MouseEvent event) {

    childrenTreeView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    childrenTreeView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();

    String tmpLocateString = txtLocate.getText().toLowerCase();
    TreeItem<APerson> item = childrenTreeView.getRoot();
    item.setExpanded(true);
    System.out.println("Locate ->"+tmpLocateString+" Root value = "+item.getValue().getPersonName());

    if (item == null) {
        // Don't do anything
        return;
    }

    if (item.getValue().getPersonName().toLowerCase().contains(tmpLocateString)){
        System.out.println("Item ->"+item+"  MATCHES (LocateClicked)");
        childrenTreeView.getSelectionModel().select(item);
    } 

    doSearch(item, tmpLocateString);

}


private void doSearch(TreeItem<APerson> item, String tmpLocateString) {

    System.out.println("Current Parent :" + item.getValue());

    if (item != childrenTreeView.getRoot()) {
        if (item.getValue().getPersonName().toLowerCase().contains(tmpLocateString)){
            System.out.println("Item ->"+item+"  MATCHES (in doSearch)");
            childrenTreeView.getSelectionModel().select(item);
        } 
    }

    for(TreeItem<APerson> child: item.getChildren()){
        String personName = child.getValue().getPersonName();
        if (personName.toLowerCase().contains(tmpLocateString)) {
            childrenTreeView.getSelectionModel().select(child);
        }

        if(child.getChildren().isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(" No Children for this node : "+personName);
        } else {
            doSearch(child, tmpLocateString);
        }
    }

}
```

After the first error, the selections work correctly for all other searches..... Can anyone guess what is wrong? "doSearch" function is recursive to walk thru entire tree.

Thanks for your help, in advance.

Hornigold

This is the change I did to onLocateClicked but it did not work.

```
    void onLocateClicked(MouseEvent event) {

    TreeItem<APerson> item = childrenTreeView.getRoot();
    if (item == null) {
        // Don't do anything
        return;
    }


    String tmpLocateString = txtLocate.getText().toLowerCase();
    childrenTreeView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    childrenTreeView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    item.setExpanded(true);
    System.out.println("Locate ->"+tmpLocateString+" Root value = "+item.getValue().getPersonName());

    if (item.getValue().getPersonName().toLowerCase().contains(tmpLocateString)){
        System.out.println("Item ->"+item+"  MATCHES (LocateClicked)");
        childrenTreeView.getSelectionModel().select(item);
    } 

    doSearch(item, tmpLocateString);

}
```

Comment: Not the problem here, but your `null` check comes a bit late. There are 2 expressions that result in a NPE for `item == null` before you do the check.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Fabian. But, why do you think so? I don't get NPE anywhere in the function onLocateClicked. See the console output. Locate ->raja Root value = Rajamanickam Aiya
Item ->TreeItem [ value: Rajamanickam Aiya ]  MATCHES (LocateClicked)
It gets the correct ROOT ITEM value.  Am I looking at the correct function?

Comment: You'd get one, if the root item was `null`, since you're doing `item.setExpanded(true);` and `item.getValue()` before checking for `null`. If you're sure the root is != null, there is no point in checking.

Comment: I mean that the ROOT NODE was available in the FIRST click of the LOCATE button.

Comment: No it does not work. See the revised code.